# Filtering multiple URLs with GA api

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a large list of URLs, that I want to use as a filter when making a request using the GA API.

Im using the dimensionfilterclauses to filter but only ever get the first value in the list in the response

This is the function im using

```
def get_report_pv(analytics, st_date, end_date):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': st_date, 'endDate': end_date}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:uniquePageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:avgTimeOnPage'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'}, {'expression': 'ga:exits'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'}],
            "orderBys": [
                {
                    "orderType": "VALUE",
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "fieldName": "ga:pageviews"
                }
            ],
            "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                            "operator": "EXACT",
                            "not": "false",
                            "expressions": [url_list]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "pageSize": 10000
            }
          ]
        }
  ).execute()
```

Is there anyway I can enter a list of URLs to use as a filter? Any reason why im only getting the first element in the response?

The workaround I have is to have a seperate response for each URL but it feels like there should be a better way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is wondering, this is how I got it to work......

I had to make a dictionary with all my filters as seperate elements inside the dictionary

something like....

```
masterFilter = []
for elem in url_list:
    filterDict = { "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "expressions": elem}
    masterFilter.append(filterDict)
```

And then just plop that list into the filters element in the request

```
{
    "filters": masterFilter
}
```

One request used each time and no issues with performance that are noticable